# Finding out number of occurence of a key in a nested JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, underscore.js

I have a nested object like

```
{
name: "John",
parent:{
 parent:{
  parent:{
  }
 }
}
}
```

Now I want to get the level of the master parent object or basically how many times a parent object has been nested. In this case, I should be getting an output of `3`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: hi @vaira I have tried the traditional for loop approach. I was hoping if there is any kind of pre-built lodash functions to do the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also do it recursively like this:

```js
const obj = {
name: "John",
parent:{
 parent:{
  parent:{
    parent:{
     parent:{
      parent:{
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
function findk(o,k,l=0){
  if (o[k]) l=findk(o[k],k,++l)
  return l
}
console.log(findk(obj,"parent"))
```

Comment: I suggest giving the parameters speaking names. Other than that, it's more or less what I would write.

Answer (score 2):

You could taken a recursive and iterative approach by checkin the handed over value, if it is an array, then check for wanted key and iterate all values of the array or return zero.

```js
const
    getCount = (object, key) => object && typeof object === 'object'
        ? (key in object) + Object
            .values(object)
            .reduce((s, o) => s + getCount(o, key), 0)
        : 0;
    
    
console.log(getCount({ name: "John", parent: { parent: { parent: {} } } }, 'parent'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = { // treat it like a tree
  name: "John",
  parent: {
    parent: {
      parent: {}
    }
  }
}

const findDepth = (root, key) => {
  let depth = 0;

  let loop = (obj) => {
    if (obj && obj[key]) {
      loop(obj[key]);
      depth++;
    }
  }
  loop(root);
  return depth;
}

const result = findDepth(obj, 'parent')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is a recursive solution which is correct, but don't you think it will add more function calls to the stack?

Comment: here function calls are not holding value, let alone a giant value, if that is not the case recursive is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
name: "John",
parent:{
 parent:{
  parent:{
    parent:{
     parent:{
      parent:{
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }

const keyToTrack = 'parent';
let current = obj[keyToTrack],
     count = 0;

while (typeof current === 'object') {
     current = current[keyToTrack];
     count += 1;
}

console.log(`The key parent appears ${count} times`)
```

The base case is when you don't find the key.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = {
  name: "John",
  parent: {
    parent: {
      parent: {}
    }
  }
}

function testObject(object, nestedObject) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (object[nestedObject]) {
      object = object[nestedObject];
      i++;
    } else {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

console.log(testObject(test, 'parent'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `while` like this:

```js
let obj = {
  name: "John",
  parent: {
    parent: {
      parent: {
        parent: {
          parent: {
            parent: {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

let key = 'parent', i = 0;
while(obj = obj[key]) ++i;

console.log(i)
```